# TSQL to Concatenate XML output

Tags: t-sql

I have an XML column in the SQL database and the value for XML is

```
<m>
  <t>1</t>
   <E>
     <I>x </I>
     <D>ErrorDescription1</D>
   </E>
</m>
<m>
  <t>2</t>
    <E>
      <I>x </I>
       <D>ErrorDescription2</D>
    </E>
 </m>
```

I need the output in a string as: x ErrorDescription1;y ErrorDescription2 .

Can you please guide how to get this output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What didn't you understand about the research you performed that would have showed you how to use Xquery in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<m>
  <t>1</t>
   <E>
     <I>x </I>
     <D>ErrorDescription1</D>
   </E>
</m>
<m>
  <t>2</t>
    <E>
      <I>y </I>
       <D>ErrorDescription2</D>
    </E>
 </m>';
```

The following statement will give you the details in tabular view:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.c)
    ,T.c.value('(./I)[1]', 'varchar(4)')
    ,T.c.value('(./D)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
FROM @xml.nodes('m/E') T(c);
```

[image]

Then, concatenate then:

```
 WITH DataSource ([RowID], [value]) AS
 (
     SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.c)
            ,T.c.value('(./I)[1]', 'varchar(4)') + T.c.value('(./D)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
     FROM @xml.nodes('m/E') T(c)
 )
 SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN [RowID] = 1 THEN [value] END) + ';'  + MAX(CASE WHEN [RowID] = 2 THEN [value] END)
 FROM DataSource
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach was a FLWOR-query:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<m>
  <t>1</t>
   <E>
     <I>x </I>
     <D>ErrorDescription1</D>
   </E>
</m>
<m>
  <t>2</t>
    <E>
      <I>y </I>
       <D>ErrorDescription2</D>
    </E>
 </m>';
```

--The query

```
 SELECT @xml.query(N'for $m in /m
                     let $t:=($m/t/text())[1] cast as xs:int?
                     let $i:=($m/E/I/text())[1]
                     let $d:=($m/E/D/text())[1]
                     order by $t
                     return  <a>{concat($i," ",$d,";")}</a>')
            .value('.','nvarchar(max)');
```

The idea in short:

- We pick the repeating `<m>` elements into a variable loop
- We use - for better readability - `let` statements to push the values into variables
- We can use `order by` (if needed)
- We use a trick with XML by returning the concatenated value *within* an element and
- then pick *the whole content* using just a `'.'` as XPath.

The only thing left for you ist the final semicolon.
You can either put it in front and use `STUFF()` to cut away the first letter, or you can use `SUBSTRING()` together with `LEN()` to cut the last letter off. Or you you might just leave it in place :-)

As in most cases there is a (not recommended) short version too:

```
 SELECT @xml.query(N'for $e in /m/E
                     return  <a>{concat(($e/I)[1]," ",($e/D)[1],";")}</a>')
            .value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```